# htaccess - replace path if query string match certain word

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following rewrite rules

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$   articles.php?t=$1&p=$2    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9-]+)/?$   articles.php?t=$1&p=$2&id=$3    [NC,L]
```

My problem is if the value of `p` is `community` I want it to redirect to community.php and preserve the query string.

so the url would become `community.php?t=$1&p=$2&id=$3` or `community.php?t=$1&p=$2`

Thanks

Comment: If you want to access the query string, you have to use a RewriteCond for that.

Comment: I know i can do `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &p=community [NC]` but I don't know how to continue after that.

Comment: Is that parameter part of the original query string? If it is just the second part of the pattern you are matching in your RewriteRules, then you make a special rule beforehand that tests for that fixed literal instead of a pattern.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `p` has 6 possible values and I don't want to write these rules one by one.

Comment: Yes, but only one of those values you want to treat specially, right?

Comment: Oh.. that works! I thought I have to use `RewriteCond` for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 additional rules like this **before your existing rules**:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-z0-9-]+/community/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ community.php?t=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[a-z0-9-]+/community/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9-]+)/?$ community.php?t=$1&p=$2&id=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response but it's still redirecting to article.php

Comment: If you have these rules in correct order then it should not happen. Please post your complete .htaccess in your question so that I can investigate and suggest.